# Eloquent default attribute values: $attributes or DB column default value?

Tags: postgresql, laravel, eloquent, doctrine

What's the proper way to implement default values for Eloquent models?

I've configured my database tables using Laravel's migrations. Some columns have default values specified. When using these tables in conjunction with Eloquent models, different things happen depending on the selected database driver:

In MySQL, when creating a new model and saving it, a DB row is inserted having the column's default value for every attribute that was not explicitly specified. **This is what I would like to happen.**

In Postgres and SQLite however, this is not the case. A PDOException is thrown:

> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column
>   "some_column" violates not-null constraint
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, null, null, null, null, null, null, 7, 8, null, 9, null, null, 10, 11, 12, null).

It is clear to me that the column is not nullable and that null values are not accepted. I would expect however that the default value was inserted instead of an error being raised.

Comment: which datatype is that variable in your migration??

Comment: @lewis4u It is a `tinyInteger`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you create your own parent model that extends Eloquent directly, and have all of your models extend this custom parent.

In the custom parent, override the `performInsert()` method to remove `null` values just before inserting. Be sure to copy the entire method from the Eloquent source code so you don't lose any important steps in the process:

```
class MyModelParent extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    /**
     * Perform a model insert operation.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function performInsert(Builder $query)
    {
        if ($this->fireModelEvent('creating') === false) {
            return false;
        }

        ... // Be sure to copy all of it!

        // This is the change you'll make. Before, it was just:
        // $attributes = $this->attributes;
        $attributes = array_filter($this->attributes, function($val){
            return $val !== null;
        });

        ... // Be sure to copy all of it!

        return true;
    }
}
```

`performUpdate()` should handle this issue fine, since it uses `getDirty()` to get the list of fields instead of accessing the property directly.

And while you're at it, you should consider submitting a patch to Laravel that would make the core Postgres-safe.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The question that remains is: what is the preferred way to implement default values for Eloquent models? This especially holds for booleans and 'enums' (just integer constants defined in the models).

Comment: @TomLank. This solution should generate an INPUT statement that ignores null values, leaving the database to take care of default values. You shouldn't have to worry about defaults in your model.

Comment: I will test this out. Ty.

Answer (score 0):

SQL NOT NULL Constraint

The NOT NULL constraint enforces a column to NOT accept NULL values.

you are adding a null value on NOT NULL column

it seems

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_notnull.asp

Comment: Okay, interesting to see that this does work in MySQL. Still, the question remains what's the right way to implement default values in Eloquent.